# Visual Studio 2008 debugger not catching exceptions

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I'm working in a new VS2008 installation with an ASP.NET web application project, and for some reason it's not catching exceptions at all. Where I used to get the helpful little green popup in the IDE notifying me of an unhandled exceptions and allowing me to examine the values of local variables etc., it now goes straight to the Yellow Screen of Death.

Debugging is working otherwise - for example I can set a breakpoint and it works normally.

I'm sure there's just an incorrect setting somewhere in Visual Studio - any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What had happened here (embarrassingly enough) is that I'd inadvertently unchecked ASP.NET in Project Properties/Web/Debuggers.

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible that all of your exceptions are being handled and therefore would not get thrown in the IDE (unless you explicitly say you want to break on handled exceptions using the Debug->Exceptions menu)

Answer (score 2):

On the debug menu -> exceptions

You can pick which exceptions to catch or not.. is this what you meant?